# Filter a view with information from the currently logged-in user profile (from the Content Profile module)

Tags: 6, views

I have the *Content Profile* module installed. With this module, each user has one to many locations that are attached to them.

These locations are created via the *Locs* content type. I have another content type (*todays_spot*) which has a single location, dynamically created via the *Locs* content type.

I'm pulling some of the *todays_spot* data out via a view, but I need to filter it so it only displays data if the user's locations match.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a node reference to the locs content?

Comment: @Westie: yes, the content profiles, as well as todays_spot uses the same Node reference to locs.

Answer (score 1):

See [Filter a view basing on a relationship to the current user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/filter-view-based-on-relationship-to-current-user) for a Drupal 7 solution. The same principle applies here.

Create an argument for the related *loc* on *todays_spot*.
Choose the the right relationship (*node*, I think), and select *Provide default argument*.
Use *PHP code* for your default argument.

You'll need to modify the code to match your system, but it should resemble the following code.

```php
// This code uses the Profile2 module. Something similar will work
// with the Content Profile module; you'll need to inspect the module
// to find a function similar to profile2_load_by_user().

global $user;
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid,'facilitator');

if (!$profile) {
  return '';
}

if (!isset($profile->field_location['und'])) {
  return '';
}

$locations = array();
foreach ($profile->field_location['und'] as $location) {
  $locations[] = $location['nid'];
}

return implode(', ', $locations);
```

Don't forget to select *Allow multiple terms per argument* before saving your new argument.